# $n^{th}$ derivative of a hypergeometric function with a second order argument

Tags: derivatives, hypergeometric-function

I know that:

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{d^n}{dz^n} {_1 F_1}(a;b;z) = \dfrac{{(a)_n}}{{(b)_n}}{_1 F_1}(a+n;b+n;z).
\end{equation}

Now what if I have, ${_1 F_1}(a;b;c x^2)$, what is

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} {_1 F_1}(a;b;c x^2)
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect? You can always use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula.

Comment: this is the first time that i have seen this formula. thanks!